# Why have I been forgotten by everyone?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've never gotten a caravan from any civilization, and immigrants only once in 5 years. The depot is accessible. Am I doing something wrong, really unlucky, or something else? How do I check if any civilizations exist?

Comment: Verify that there are other actual civilizations in existence.

Comment: @ShaneC I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the civilizations screen (default: <kbd>c</kbd>) to see if there's a dwarf civ nearby. According to [this](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=46421.0), you may be the last of your people.

Comment: There is a dwarf civ listed, but I have "no agreements with this land" and it has "no important leaders".

Comment: I've been in that boat antony. You just happen to be in place where no one else is around. you've probably also never been attacked by goblins before either right? There are just no other civs around you. But the fact that you haven't gotten even a caravan from the dwarves is a little odd. are you sure your market's access reaches all the way to every edge of the map? they not be coming from an direction that allows easy access. Your migration problem will be solved by the caravan problem. The caravan brings news of your fort to other forts, richer safer forts attract migrants.

Comment: @Narcolapser I get 2-3 goblin ambushes a year, half the time 2 at a time.

Comment: wow. that is really odd. is the goblin civ listed on the screen with the dwarven one?

Comment: @Narc yep, with some significant leaders listed, unlike the dwarf civ.

Comment: ah, then sjohn must be right. everyone else is dead. intense!

Comment: I wish I still had this fort.